# Representar coordenadas em vetor de Matlab

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, matriz, matlab

Estou com problemas na criação de um vetor de objetos em Matlab, a ideia é que seja um vetor de coordenadas, i.e. as posições x e y.
O objetivo é ter um vetor para acessar as coordenadas nos loops facilmente, e ter atomicidade dos dados para ter consistência de qual posição é x ou y.
Creio que tem que usar construtor.

Dado um n de entrada será construído um array de coordenadas de tamanho n. No qual cada elemento terá seu próprio x e y.
Ex:

```
n=2;
vetor(n)=coord(0,0);
vetor(1).x=5;vetor(1).y=3;
vetor(2).x=2;vetor(2).y=4;
```

A questão principal é que quero deixar a instância vetor em uma outra classe, que terá que ter no construtor a alocação desse array de n posições.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um vetor único para as posições x e y, acho que o certo seria uma matriz com as posições, mas em todo caso para simplificar já pensou em usar algo parecido com hash ou dicionários (scalar structure), você pode criar um dicionário chamado coordenada, dentro dele crie as coordenadas X e Y correspondentes, você pode usar algo assim:

```
%coloque os valores correspondentes a suas coordenadas, veja um exemplo
coordenada.X=[1 2 3 4 5]
coordenada.Y=[1 2 3 4 5]
%agora faça um loop para acessar suas coordenadas assim:
for i=1:length(coordenada.X)
     X=coordenada.X(i)
     Y=coordenada.Y(i)
 end
```

Seguindo o exemplo que você mostrou e que acabou de editar, você pode alocar o tamanho de cada vetor no matlab em memória usando zeros, veja:

```
n=2;

%alocando o espaço necessário
coordenada.X=zeros(n,1);
coordenada.Y=zeros(n,1);

%agora popule suas coordenadas
coordenada.X(1)=5; coordenada.Y(1)=3
.
.
.
```

Neste caso é só passar a instancia coordenada para a sua outra classe.

Comment: Não é viável fazer isto no meu caso são muitas coordenadas. Consegui uma solução utilizando a classe java.awt.Point do java num java array em Matlab, mas ainda gostaria de construir o vetor de coordenadas no próprio Matlab sem depender do Java.

Comment: é que não ficou muito claro o seu problema, um vetor de coordenadas da espaço para muitos tipos de implementaçõe,s eu aconselho você demonstrar um exemplo de como você espera que este vetor seje ...

Comment: Certo vou editar.

Comment: da uma olhada se é mais ou menos isso que precisa ..

Comment: Tive que usar um construtor pra cada classe mesmo, e se a outra não tivesse construtor não fazia nada. Contudo pelo esforço vou te pontuar.